# AngularJS - Access isolate scope when using "controller as" syntax in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was reading [a very interesting resource](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#directives-and-controlleras) and I stumbled across this piece of code:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myExample', myExample);

function myExample() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'app/feature/example.directive.html',
        scope: {
            max: '='
        },
        link: linkFunc,
        controller: ExampleController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true // because the scope is isolated
    };
    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
        console.log('LINK: scope.min = %s *** should be undefined', scope.min);
        console.log('LINK: scope.max = %s *** should be undefined', scope.max);
        console.log('LINK: scope.vm.min = %s', scope.vm.min);
        console.log('LINK: scope.vm.max = %s', scope.vm.max);
    }
}

ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ExampleController($scope) {
    // Injecting $scope just for comparison
    var vm = this;
    vm.min = 3;
    console.log('CTRL: $scope.vm.min = %s', $scope.vm.min);
    console.log('CTRL: $scope.vm.max = %s', $scope.vm.max);
    console.log('CTRL: vm.min = %s', vm.min);
    console.log('CTRL: vm.max = %s', vm.max);
}
```

What got most of my curiosity was the

`console.log('LINK: scope.max = %s *** should be undefined', scope.max);`

in the directive's link function. I don't understand why `scope.max` should be `undefined`. `vm` is defined in the controller, so why does the `max` attribute – which is directly defined in the directive's isolate scope – must be accessed through it on the link function? Is it related to using the `controller as` syntax on the directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's the `bindToController` option that is the important bit here. It binds the isolate scope variables to the controller rather than the scope. Thus, there is no `max` property on the scope, just on the controller instance. This controller instance is then assigned to a property on the `$scope` when you use `controllerAs` so, in your example, you would see `vm` as a property on your `$scope` object if you were to log it in the console for example.

You can read more about `bindToController` in the `$compile` section in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile